# Absurdly high reallocated sector count (LITEON SSD)

Tags: ssd

I recently received a stash of SSDs from a computer lab which didn’t need them anymore. Some of the SSDs are bad, but most are fine.

One in particular had some very strange SMART data, saying attribute 5 (Reallocated Sector Count) has a raw value of 119537664. That’s over 100 million sectors, which seemed totally implausible. Also, the “normalized” value was sitting at 100, which means everything was ok.

When I converted the number to hex, it came up as 0x7200000, which is a suspiciously round number, so I suspect the number is encoded somehow (i.e. it doesn’t actually have 100 million reallocated sectors).

Is there any way to get the “real” reallocated sector count?

Comment: Have you used the manufacturers software to determine if there is a problem?

Comment: You're right that raw data is probably not a sector count. The raw data is manufacturer specific. The most important thing is if the SMART system reports any impending failure. So if it says the drive is good, it probably is. Here's a good link although it kind of contradicts what I said about the reallocated sectors count. http://www.z-a-recovery.com/manual/smart.aspx